# MERN Stack Development - StripeAuthenticationError

Tags: stripe-payments

When I go for Checkout It's giving error. The following error occurs. Please someone help.

Error:
{
"type": "StripeAuthenticationError",
"raw": {
"message": "You did not provide an API key. You need to provide your API key in the Authorization header, using Bearer auth (e.g. 'Authorization: Bearer YOUR_SECRET_KEY'). See https://stripe.com/docs/api#authentication for details, or we can help at [https://support.stripe.com/."](https://support.stripe.com/.%22),
"type": "invalid_request_error",
"headers": {
"server": "nginx",
"date": "Mon, 04 Oct 2021 04:55:24 GMT",
"content-type": "application/json",
"content-length": "343",
"connection": "keep-alive",
"access-control-allow-credentials": "true",
"access-control-allow-methods": "GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS, DELETE",
"access-control-allow-origin": "*",
"access-control-expose-headers": "Request-Id, Stripe-Manage-Version, X-Stripe-External-Auth-Required, X-Stripe-Privileged-Session-Required",
"access-control-max-age": "300",
"cache-control": "no-cache, no-store",
"www-authenticate": "Basic realm="Stripe"",
"strict-transport-security": "max-age=31556926; includeSubDomains; preload"
},
"statusCode": 401
},
"rawType": "invalid_request_error",
"headers": {
"server": "nginx",
"date": "Mon, 04 Oct 2021 04:55:24 GMT",
"content-type": "application/json",
"content-length": "343",
"connection": "keep-alive",
"access-control-allow-credentials": "true",
"access-control-allow-methods": "GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS, DELETE",
"access-control-allow-origin": "*",
"access-control-expose-headers": "Request-Id, Stripe-Manage-Version, X-Stripe-External-Auth-Required, X-Stripe-Privileged-Session-Required",
"access-control-max-age": "300",
"cache-control": "no-cache, no-store",
"www-authenticate": "Basic realm="Stripe"",
"strict-transport-security": "max-age=31556926; includeSubDomains; preload"
},
"statusCode": 401
}

```
const Cart = () => {
  const cart = useSelector((state) => state.cart);
  const [stripeToken, setstripeToken] = useState(null);
  const history = useHistory();

  const onToken = (token) => {
    setstripeToken(token);
    console.log(token);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const makeRequest = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await userRequest.post("/checkout/payment", {
          tokenId: stripeToken.id,
          amount: cart.total,          
        });
        
        history.push("/success", { data: res.data });
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    };
    stripeToken && makeRequest();
  }, [stripeToken, cart.total, history]);

  console.log(stripeToken);
  
  return (
    <Container>
      <Navbar />
      <Announcement />
      <Wrapper>
        <Title>YOUR BAG</Title>
        <Top>
          <TopButton>CONTINUE SHOPPING</TopButton>
          <TopTexts>
            <TopText></TopText>
            <TopText></TopText>
          </TopTexts>

          <TopButton type="filled">CHECKOUT NOW</TopButton>
        </Top>
        <Bottom>
          <Info>
            {cart.products.map((product) => (
              <Product>
                <ProductDetail>
                  <Image src={product.img} />
                  <Details>
                    <ProductName>
                      <b>Product: </b>
                      {product.title}
                    </ProductName>
                    <ProductId>
                      <b>ID: </b>
                      {product._id}
                    </ProductId>
                    <ProductColor color={product.color}></ProductColor>
                    <ProductSize>
                      <b>Size: </b>
                      {product.size}
                    </ProductSize>
                  </Details>
                </ProductDetail>
                <PriceDetail>
                  <ProductAmountContainer>
                    <Add />
                    <ProductAmount>{product.quantity}</ProductAmount>
                    <Remove />
                  </ProductAmountContainer>
                  <ProductPrice>
                    Rs.{product.price * product.quantity}
                  </ProductPrice>
                </PriceDetail>
              </Product>
            ))}
            <Hr />
          </Info>
          <Summary>
            <SummaryTitle>ORDER SUMMARY</SummaryTitle>
            <SummaryItem>
              <SummaryItemText>Subtotal</SummaryItemText>
              <SummaryItemPrice>Rs.{cart.total}</SummaryItemPrice>
            </SummaryItem>
            <SummaryItem>
              <SummaryItemText>Estimated Shipping</SummaryItemText>
              <SummaryItemPrice>$58</SummaryItemPrice>
            </SummaryItem>
            <SummaryItem>
              <SummaryItemText>Shipping Discount</SummaryItemText>
              <SummaryItemPrice>- 48</SummaryItemPrice>
            </SummaryItem>
            <SummaryItem type="total">
              <SummaryItemText>Total</SummaryItemText>
              <SummaryItemPrice>Rs.{cart.total}</SummaryItemPrice>
            </SummaryItem>
            <StripeCheckout
              stripeKey={process.env.REACT_APP_STRIPE}
              name="Abdul Rasheed Azar"
              billingAddress
              shippingAddress
              image="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/ogw/ADea4I5yCEiXHB4_cZLjQevNUl8jMyGCJsUYPDecFVaA6Q=s83-c-mo"
              description={`Your total is Rs.${cart.total}`}
              amount={cart.total * 100}
              token={onToken}
              
            >
              <Button>CHECKOUT NOW</Button>
            </StripeCheckout>
          </Summary>
        </Bottom>
      </Wrapper>

      <Footer />
    </Container>
  );
};
```

`

Comment: can you please console log process.env.REACT_APP_STRIPE

Comment: Also this is a legacy usage of Stripe, you really should not be using it this way at all. (https://stripe.com/docs/legacy-checkout)

Answer (score 0):

had the same issue as you, my fix, and assuming your code is all correct you have to make a change in your API folder for its env file. stripe has implemented a change most likely recently to where it has specific names it needs you to use for certain keys specifically in this case where you need to update its secret key name in the API folders env file to STRIPE_SECRET_KEY_MY ,
for more details https://github.com/stripe/stripe-react-native/blob/ef674b2b87b8e453a077a5565859d6489870386f/example/server/index.ts#L50-L74